# UAG 2010 and Exchange 2010 Service Pack installs

Tags: exchange-2010, service-pack, microsoft-forefront-2010

We are currently on Exchange 2010 SP2 and UAG 2010 SP1.  I want to upgrade Exchange to SP3, and later on UAG to SP4, but not all at the same time due to scheduling.  Ideally we'd like to do Exchange first, then a week later update UAG.

Will Exchange 2010 SP3 be supported (function) on UAG SP1?  Should we update UAG to SP4 first, then later update Exchange?

Comment: What is UAG?...

Comment: Unified Access Gateway, specifically marketed by Microsoft as "Forefront Unified Access Gateway" (the successor to Microsoft IAS).  Reverse proxy server, vpn access.  Our Exchange OWA is published via UAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on info from a MS Forum, there is no incompatibility with UAG 2010 SP1 and Exchange 2010 SP3.  I can also confirm this works based on my experience.